# How to monitor nginx running on a docker container with ngxtop running on my mac host?

Tags: nginx, docker

The official Nginx Docker image does a redirection of access.log to /dev/stdout, so that one can access the log with `docker log` from outside docker i.e. on the host. This is an issue because then from within the docker container I can't access access.log.

I finally resorted to install nginx on my mac and perform the following command
 `docker logs -f competent_edison  &>> ~/Dev/monitoring/access.log`

While the redirection works fine and the access.log on my mac, mirror the output of the container in realtime, ngxtop output nothing when i pass that file as parameter: `ngnix -l ~/Dev/monitoring/access.log`

I wonder if there is a way for ngxtop to be installed on an host, to monitor an nginx running in a container.

Please any indication would be helpful as i spend 2 days around that and can't figure out how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Do something like

`docker logs -f <nginx-pod-name> | tee -a <nginx-pod-name>.log > /dev/null & docker run -t --rm -v <nginx-pod-name>.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log:ro mishunika/ngxtop`

So to break that down: `docker logs -f <nginx-pod-name>` gets the log stream.

Then `| tee -a <nginx-pod-name>.log > /dev/null` is piping the output to `tee` which is appending to a file on your host (while silencing STDOUT).

Finally, you launch ngxtop and mount the log file from your host to the ngxtop container via `docker run -t --rm -v <nginx-pod-name>.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log:ro mishunika/ngxtop`.

This solution doesn't account for rotating the local log file but I'm assuming this is from troubleshooting purposes so that's not necessary.